# Configuring multiple scheme in iOS causes mismatch in flavors

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

I have a Flutter Project, I have created two separate firebase projects(not two apps in same firebase project). I am setting two different schemes for my iOS app. I have following commands to use different projects accordingly

1.`flutter run --release --flavor prod`
2.`flutter run --release --flavor dev`

For dev flavour it need to use the dev project created in firebase but it uses the production firebase project and vice versa.

The configuration works properly for Android and not for iOS.

I am following the below tutorials for iOS setup

https://www.tengio.com/blog/multiple-firebase-environments-with-flutter/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdqnxcV7_FY&feature=emb_logo

As you can see below image for how I have setup my Google services file. I have checked many times and I am not mismatching those files by putting prod in dev and vice versa.

Following is my script

[image]

[image]

I have also added the Google services file to targets.
I tried removing the checkmark of targets as well for Google services file but still same issue.

One thing I noticed is that if I add the prod google services file after the dev google services file to my iOS project it always use the prod environment irrespective of flavor. If I add dev after prod then it uses dev environment of firebase irrespective of flavor. Even changing the command line build options in xcode does not work for me.

Comment: Hello Are you still facing this issue??
Also can u you tell me whether are you using multiple targets?
can you post screen shot of targets panel??

Comment: I have React Native app which has 3 tragets 
1 for debug,1 staging,1 release

What i do is just the Set the correct target membership for the GoogleService-Info.plist and it works as expected.

I didn't have to use any script at all also 
only one plist is at root and other 2 in subfolders all works smoothly

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar But that approach is not working for me

Comment: Do you have multiple targets??

Comment: Can u post screenshots of the target panel

Answer (score 4):

`GoogleService-Info.plist` must be on project's root directory.
Move all `GoogleService-Info.plist` to project's root, change their name. for example add scheme to the name like `GoogleService-Info-prod.plist`

and change your command to

```
cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-prod.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

do this for all schemes

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In Native ios development, info plist should be at root but in Flutter plist should at root of Runner. I pretty sure these wont solve the issue

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Are you a Flutter developer?

Comment: I suggest doing this just for the iOS version. I don't know many thing about flutter, but when you want build your project with Xcode it should be in project's root.

Comment: Yeah this is a Flutter issue. Check this out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18342